# trigonometric relationship to get unitaire vector

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

i'm  looking for relation between angles thats enable  the trigonometric vector $u$ to be unitaire i.e
$ u = [{\cos}({\theta _1}),{\cos}({\theta _2}),.....{\cos}({\theta _N})]$

and $||u||_2^2 = 1$.
where $N>2$

Comment: Well...there's the obvious $\theta_2 = \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta_1$, and all other $\theta_i$ are $\pi/2$. Can you give any hint of what kind of thing you might mean?

Answer (score 1):

i found that :
$\begin{split}R \triangleq \frac{\sin(N \frac{1}{2}d)}{\sin(\frac{1}{2} d)} \\
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \cos(a + nd) =
\begin{cases}
N \cos a & \text{if } \sin(\frac{1}{2}d) = 0 \\
R \cos ( a + (N - 1) \frac{1}{2} d) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\\
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \sin(a + nd) =
\begin{cases}
N \sin a & \text{if } \sin(\frac{1}{2}d) = 0 \\
R \sin ( a + (N - 1) \frac{1}{2} d) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\end{split}$
so i thinks that for given $N$ and any angle $a$ we can find $d$ numerically  ?

2{\cos ^2}({\theta _1}) = 1 + \cos (2{\theta _1})$

so we must find $d$ that verify :

$R(2 - N) = 1$